# Matrix of $T$ for the linear transformation $T:\mathcal{M}_{2\times 3}\longrightarrow\mathcal{M}_{3\times 2}$ where $T(A)=A^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to figure out a matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathcal{M}_{2\times 3}$ (let's call this basis $B$)  for the linear transformation

$T: \mathcal{M}_{2\times 3}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{3\times 2}$

and $T$ is supposed to be the transpose linear transformation.

I know that we need $[T]_B$ such that any $2 \times 3$ matrix multiplied by $[T]_B$ will give us a $3\times 2$ matrix. My issue is I'm having trouble coming up with this matrix.

I think the transformation matrix would need to be multiplied on the left because otherwise you will still have two rows in the final product instead of three. So $[T]_B$ should have at least three rows. I was told that $[T]_B$ would be a six by six matrix but I'm not sure I fully understand how that could work.

Comment: Is it even possible to multiply 2×3 matrix ro anything to get 3×2 matrix?

Comment: In what order are you listing the six elements of the basis of $M_{2\times 3}$? Your matrix for $T$ will be a $6\times 6$ matrix of course. It does not "multiply a $3\times 2$ matrix", it operates on at $6\times 1$ vector, carrying it to another $6\times 1$ vector.

Comment: Matrix of a linear transformation $T$ multiplies "coordinate vector" of any element $v$ and gives coordinate vector of the element $T(v)$. Suppose the basis is $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ then you you can write any element $v$ as $v = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n$ . $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ is the coordinate vector of $v$ and if $A$ is matrix of $T$ for this basis then $A[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ is the coordinate vector of $T(v)$. A nice way to put it is as

$T\Bigg([v_1\ldots v_n]\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) =[v_1\ldots v_n] A\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n
\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Such a matrix is called a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

Comment: What you propose ("$[T]_B$ such that any $2\times 3$  matrix multiplied by $[T]_B$ will give us a $3\times 2$ matrix") is not possible.  Check the number of columns in the result of any such matrix multiplication.  This was previously discussed in [Finding a matrix representation of the transpose transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299901/finding-a-matrix-representation-of-the-transpose-transformation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a matrix representation of the transpose transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299901/finding-a-matrix-representation-of-the-transpose-transformation)

Comment: @TonyPizza That's what I was thinking. I've been deliberating over this for days because I couldn't think of a way it was possible. I figured if I was being asked to _find_ the matrix for $T$ then it _should_ exist. I thought maybe I was just missing something so I posted here, glad to know I'm not the only one confused by the question haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $2  \times 3$ matrices $E_{11},E_{12},E_{13}, E_{21},E_{22},E_{23}$
such that $E_{ij}$ is a matrix with $1$ in the ${ij}$ entry and $0$ everywhere else. This gives a basis for the vector space $M_{2 \times 3}$.

Similarly define the set of $3\times 2$ matrices $F_{11},F_{12},F_{21},F_{22},F_{31},F_{32}$ which form a basis for $M_{3\times 2}$.

By the definition of the matrix of a linear transformation we know that the columns of $[T]_B$ will be the coordinates of $T(E_{11}),T(E_{12}),T(E_{13}), T(E_{21}),T(E_{22}),T(E_{23})$ in the basis $F_{11},F_{12},F_{21},F_{22},F_{31},F_{32}.$
That is, $$T(E_{11}) = F_{11} = (1,0,0,0,0,0)^t = \text{first column of matrix}$$
$$ T(E_{12}) = F_{21} = (0,0,1,0,0,0)^t = \text{second column of matrix}$$
$$ T(E_{13}) = F_{31} = (0,0,0,0,1,0)^t = \text{third column of matrix}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$T(E_{23}) = F_{32} = (0,0,0,0,0,1)^t = \text{sixth column of matrix}.$$

Comment: This really helped a lot, thanks!